# Qt accessing model data outside ItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

I have some model class that inherits `QAbstractListModel`:

`VehiclesModel.h`:

```
class VehiclesModel : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        enum Roles {
            ImagePathRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,   // QString
            NameRole                            // QString
        };

        virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const override { ... }
        virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const override { ... }
        virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override {
            QHash<int, QByteArray> roles = QAbstractListModel::roleNames();

            roles[ImagePathRole] = "imagePath";
            roles[NameRole] = "name";

            return roles;
        }
};
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "VehiclesModel.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    VehiclesModel vehiclesModel;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("vehiclesModel", &vehiclesModel);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

And `ComboBox` that displays this model:
`main.qml`:

```
ComboBox {
    id: control
    model: vehiclesModel
    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        contentItem: RowLayout {
            Image {
                source: imagePath
            }
            Label {
                text: name
            }
        }
        highlighted: control.highlightedIndex == index
    }
    contentItem: RowLayout {
        Image {
            source: ??imagePath??
        }
        Label {
            text: ??name??
        }
    }
}
```

I want to customize the `ComboBox` to show vehicle image and name. I can access to model data from `ItemDelegate` but how to access to model data outside the `ItemDelegate`? For example I want to access current index data (`ImagePathRole` and `NameRole`) to display vehicle image and name in `contentItem`.

Is it possible to do it without calling `QAbstractListModel` methods directly (i.e. `index()` and `data()` methods) and making them `Q_INVOKABLE`?

Comment: I suggest you to not expose premitive datatypes on your models, use QObjects with properties for your data, this way you don't have to worry about setters, signals datachanged etc,  and this also allows you to pass an instance of a delegate (which is essentially a QObject) wherever you want. There is [`QQmlListProperty`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmllistproperty.html) for this.

Answer (score 3):

Not in any sort of a decent built-in way at the present time, unfortunately, this is something I've found to be lacking for quite a while, and I've considered implementing something for this in the QML models functionality, but I haven't yet had the time to do so.

For the time being, you can either do it yourself (like you're discussing), at the cost of type-safety and so on, or (the way I've typically tackled this before), you can create a QObject subclass to represent a single item in the model (ItemDataThing or whatever you choose to call it); provide it with a source model & index, properties, and let it represent a single instance of data from the model.

Something like:

```
class ImageDataThing : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString imagePath READ imagePath NOTIFY imagePathChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QAbstractItemModel* model READ model WRITE setModel NOTIFY modelChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int index READ index WRITE setIndex NOTIFY indexChanged)

public:
    QString imagePath() const;
    QAbstractItemModel *model() const;
    void setModel(const QAbstractItemModel *newModel);
    int index() const;
    void setIndex(int newIndex);
signals:
    void imagePathChanged(const QString &imagePath);
    void modelChanged(QAbstractItemModel *model);
    void indexChanged(int indexChanged);
};
```

... and in your implementation, whenever the model is set, hook the change signals (e.g. rowsInserted, rowsRemoved, ...) to alter the stored index (if provided) to keep it mapped to the correct place in the model.

In the model data getters (here, imagePath for instance), access the model instance (using the index) to grab the data out, and return it.

This has the obvious disadvantage of being a lot of boilerplate, but on the other hand, it's easy-to-write code if you are familiar with models, type-safe, and one could autogenerate it fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own function to get data from the model, like the one I'm currently using,
`VehiclesModel.h`:

```
public slots:
    int size() const;   // to access from QML javascript
    QVariant getData(int index, int role);  // to access from QML javascript
```

`VehiclesModel.cpp`:

```
int VehiclesModel::size() const {
    return m_list.size();
}

QVariant VehiclesModel::getData(int index, int role) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= m_list.count())
        return QVariant();
    switch (role) {
    case ImagePathRole:
        return ...
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to look at the  *Qt QML Tricks* library made by Thomas Boutroue:

https://gitlab.com/qt-qml-libraries-4-me/qt-qml-tricks-ng

More specific the **`QQmlObjectListModel`** (from the `Qt QML Models`) could do the trick for you.

Expanding with using the `Qt Super-Macros`, it reduces overhead writing setters/getters!
These macros basically expand to a Q_PROPERTY, resulting in accessibility from QML, and add definition of a setter, getter and private variable.

Usage in your specific case this could look something like this, quickly written down, not validated (check using the correct index for referencing the model):

`VehicleItem.h`:

```
#include <QObject>
#include "QQmlVarPropertyHelpers.h" // Include library Qt Super-Macros

class VehicleItem : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    QML_WRITABLE_VAR_PROPERTY(QString, imagePath)
    QML_WRITABLE_VAR_PROPERTY(QString, name)

public:
    explicit VehicleItem(QString imagePath, QString name, QObject* parent=0)
    : QObject   (parent)
    , m_imagePath (imagePath)
    , m_name      (name)
    {}

};
```

`VehiclesModel.h`:

```
#include <QObject>
#include "QQmlObjectListModel.h" // Include library Qt QML Models
#include "VehicleItem.h"

class VehiclesModel : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    QML_OBJMODEL_PROPERTY(VehicleItem, modelList)

public:
    explicit VehiclesModel(QObject *parent = 0);

};
```

`VehiclesModel.c`:

```
#include "VehiclesModel.h"

VehiclesModel::VehiclesModel(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent), m_modelList(new QQmlObjectListModel<VehicleItem>())
{}
```

`main.c (remains the same)`:

```
#include "VehiclesModel.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    VehiclesModel vehiclesModel;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("vehiclesModel", &vehiclesModel);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

`main.qml`:

```
ComboBox {
    id: control
    model: vehiclesModel
    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        contentItem: RowLayout {
            Image {
                source: imagePath
            }
            Label {
                text: name
            }
        }
        highlighted: control.highlightedIndex == index
    }
    contentItem: RowLayout {
        Image {
            source: vehiclesModel.modelList.get(index).imagePath
        }
        Label {
            text: vehiclesModel.modelList.get(index).name
        }
    }
}
```

As modelList (and also imagePath and name) is expanded by the macro to a Q_PROPERTY, it is accessible from QML side.

For the ins-and-outs of this library, be sure to check Thomas Boutroue's lightning talk at the QtWS2015: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96XAaH97XYo

Comment: How is it "exactly what OP is looking for" ? Can you please explain it in your answer ? What do you mean by "easy and nice syntax with minimal overhead writing your setters/getters" ? How is that relevant to the question ? I also don't see the point of your last sentence (the Q_PROPERTYs are used to define the roles of the model, not to be able to access the model in QML)

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer and showing how the lib could be used. My questions still remain not answered, expected the 2 first ones.
By easy and nice syntax, I believe you are talking about his qt-supermacros lib, which is not clear you are using in your answer. Your sentence about Q_PROPERTY is still not clear and pretty vague.

Comment: Thanks for pushing to provide decent answers/clarification. Hopefully covered it now...

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Contacted Thomas Boutroue, and his sources are now here: https://gitlab.com/qt-qml-libraries-4-me/qt-qml-tricks-ng

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug for my [SortFilterProxyModel library](https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel).

The problem you are asking is actually a head-scratching scenario. I've found a way to do it somewhat correctly but it's kinda complicated and involves an external library. In my solution we filter the source model to only expose the element corresponding to the current index of the combo box and instantiate a delegate for this element and use it as the `contentItem` of the `ComboBox`.

This has the advantage of not having to modify your model and keeping in synch with your model changes.

```
import SortFilterProxyModel 0.2 // from https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel
import QtQml 2.2

/*
...
*/

ComboBox {
    id: control
    model: vehiclesModel
    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        contentItem: RowLayout {
            Image {
                source: imagePath
            }
            Label {
                text: name
            }
        }
        highlighted: control.highlightedIndex == index
    }
    contentItem: { currentIndex; return selectedInstantiator.object; } // use currentIndex to force the binding reevaluation. When the model changes, the instantiator doesn't notify object has changed
    Instantiator {
        id: selectedInstantiator
        model: SortFilterProxyModel {
            sourceModel: control.model
            filters: IndexFilter {
                minimumIndex: control.currentIndex
                maximumIndex: control.currentIndex
            }
        }
        delegate: RowLayout {
            Image {
                source: imagePath
            }
            Label {
                text: name
            }
        }
    }
}
```