# How can I get the roles of a few currentItem from a listview in qml?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

How can I get the roles of a few currentItem from a listview in qml?

Something like:

```
ListView {
    id: listview
    model: myModel
    delegate: Item {
        property variant myData: model
        Text {
            text: model.text
        }
        Text {
            text: model.moreText
        }
    }
    onCurrentIndexChanged:{
        listview.currentItem[currentIndex].myData.text
        listview.currentItem[currentIndex + 1].myData.text
        listview.currentItem[currentIndex + 2].myData.text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really a good "generic" way to do this at this time, so the answer depends on your model type. If you are using ListModel for instance, you can use [ListModel::get](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#get-method). If you are using a C++ model, I'd recommend taking a look at the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591544/qt-accessing-model-data-outside-itemdelegate/).

Answer (score 1):

From a few `currentItem`? Isn't `currentItem` singular?
`currentItem` points to a currently *selected* `Item` and is not a list of `Item`**s**.

Maybe you want to have this:

```
myModel.get(currentIndex + i).myRole
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the role indexes of your model you could do `myModel.data(myModel.index(currentIndex, 0), roleIndex)`